# What are the advantages of using DOMParser for SVG with 'image/svg+xml' instead of 'application/xml'

Tags: javascript, xml, svg

The [DOMParser](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMParser)'s 'parseFromString' method allows HTML, XML or SVG nodes to be created from a markup string, using JavaScript. I see that the SVG mime type `image/svg+xml` can be used, but that is only supported in IE10, whereas `application/xml` is supported in IE9. I can't detect any difference using one or the other with Firefox, Chrome or Safari. Is there any advantage or difference in the results when using `image/svg+xml`?

And for that matter, I also see `text/xml` in use, as opposed to `application/xml`. Is there any difference there?